# How to implement python script code into adf

Tags: azure-data-factory

In Azure data factory I need my python script to work with the other pipeline components during the ETL process.
I need something similar to the script component. The point would be to be able to link this to the rest of my pipeline

I tried the batch component but it didn't work, because for some reason it doesn't run even though I set everything up correctly

How can resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Azure function or even Azure automation msft offerings as they too support python environments and can be integrated with adf.
Wrt Azure batch, what error are you getting?

Comment: In the batch component I created a batch pool, then uploaded my python file to a datalake.

In the batch settings, I wrote "python test.py" in the command section, but when I run the pipeline in debug mode, the status does not change to "Success". It looks like it is "stuck" in "In Progress" state.